# KIPO IPEA Timeline, IPEA processing times

Tags: ipea, kipo

I have recently requested for an international preliminary examination authority from the Korean Intellectual Property Office. It is over 20 months from my earliest priority date.
Is there any guidelines how fast IPEA has to finnish an examination?

When should I expect to receive the examination?

Answer (score 1):

From the WIPO rules:

> THE INTERNATIONAL PRELIMINARY REPORT ON PATENTABILITY (CHAPTER II OF THE PCT)

**Article 35(1) Rule 69.2   10.074.**   When must the international preliminary report on patentability (Chapter II of the PCT) be established?  The time limit for establishment of the international preliminary report on patentability (Chapter II of the PCT) is whichever of the following which expires last:  *28 months from the priority date*;  six months from the time provided under Rule 69.1 for the start of the international preliminary examination;  or six months from the date of receipt by the International Preliminary Examining Authority of the translation furnished under Rule 55.2 (see paragraphs 10.051 to 10.055). Thus, under normal circumstances, the applicant receives the report, at the latest, two months before national processing at the elected Offices may start.  This ensures that he has time to consider whether, and in which elected Offices, he wants to enter the national phase and to prepare the necessary action (for details, see National Phase).**

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the helpful information. Further question, given that the IPEA returns positive, Can I file action with it in the United States? California circuit court?